# How to generate swagger api-docs.json in php/laravel for multiple endpoints on same controller

Tags: laravel, api, swagger, voyager, swagger-php

All my api endpoints are pointed to same controller and have difference responses
e.g. /api/tags, /api/currencies, /api/countries are pointing to one BaseController

Should I write swagger annotations multiple time on same controller function or is there any way to generate api-docs.json dynamically?

Comment: See https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2018/adding-auto-generated-docs-to-laravel-api-kushy/